# Kiosk proximity sensor

Tags: proximity-sensor, windows

I am designing an information kiosk with touch screen to display information in a museum. I would like to provide it with a proximity sensor so that the dormant screen would come on whenever a visitor is close to the screen. control under windows 7 would be nice so that a software script would run at the same time.. What is the best way to achieve this ?..

Comment: Probably an IR motion sensor or simple detection of ambient light change - note how many big-box stores dim their freezer cases until you walk into the aisle.  Possible an old-style microwave motion detector.  Or maybe, for very close ranges, a capacitance setup.  Something like an Arduino Leonardo that can emulate an HID device like a mouse might not be a bad experimental interface - when your decided sensor condition is met, simulate a mouse movement or keypress to wake up the windows box.

Comment: To get some clever ideas, search for other proximity sensor questions on this server.

Answer (score 1):

Many good ideas for a detection sensor were already mentioned above, 
I would like to add an ultrasonic sensor.

Comment: Good point - they are cheap, easy to work with, and easily gated to ignore echoes beyond the range of interest.  But you might need beam modifications or multiple units to cover a wide viewing angle if that is desired.